# Is there a way to automatically run a formula a single time?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Let's say I have a table:

| Quantity | Item | Value | Fetched Item | Suggestion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Meat | Variable | Meat | ... |

The cells in the Value column have a VLOOKUP formula to fetch the value of items with the same name as "Item", and returns "Variable" if there isn't a good fit (which means there are multiple options). The Cells in the Suggestion column have a VLOOKUP formula to fetch the lowest value item in a category with the same name as "Item", and returns "" if there isn't such a category (which means the item would have been found in the value column's search). After the search, the table looks like this:

| Quantity | Item | Value | Fetched Item | Suggestion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Meat | Variable | Meat | Cow Meat |

Now, columns D and E aren't going to be used, so the user changes column B to have the suggested item.

| Quantity | Item | Value | Fetched Item | Suggestion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Cow Meat | 300 | Meat | Cow Meat |

So I don't want the user to have to put "meat" in the "Fetched Item" column for it to work, so let's say that column just has a simple `=B2` formula in it. The sheet now looks like this:

| Quantity | Item | Value | Fetched Item | Suggestion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Cow Meat | 300 | Cow Meat |  |

However, the sheet that the Suggestion formula references updates the values regularly, so fast forward to the point where cow meat now costs more than pig meat. I want the table to look like this:

| Quantity | Item | Value | Fetched Item | Suggestion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Cow Meat | 300 | Meat | Pig Meat |

This way, the user can update column B accordingly. This means that I need some way for column D to automatically copy the content of column B *if* column C reads "Variable", while ignoring future changes to column B.

`=IF($C5="Variable",[copy $B5],"")`

Something like this, I guess? I guess the easiest way to put this is "Is there a way to automatically run a formula a single time?", which is better than my old title of "Take a "snapshot" of data when referencing a cell so it doesn't change if the referenced cell does?", so I've changed it accordingly.

Comment: No. Formula can't be run once. You should use a script.

Comment: As Krzysztof said, you might need Apps Script for that. Would you be willing to use that? If that's the case, would you consider providing a copy of the spreadsheet?

Comment: I've never used scripts before, but I'm willing to try, I guess. [Here's the link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ch0azJACMD1DfrPUB4PIdUBOOhUdTechMGxIXmk1HJY/edit?usp=sharing) to a copy that y'all can edit.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the desired behavior. I guess only the first time column B is updated, should column D update with column B's value? And if column B is later updated, this update should be ignored and not copied to column D?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using onEdit:

You could use an [onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite), using Apps Script (click `Tools > Script editor`, copy the function below and save the project).

(For this to work, please create a new column (`G`), which will be used to store information on whether there were previous copies. You can then hide it.)

This function would execute every time a user edits the spreadsheet, and it would do the following, using the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events):

- Check whether edited column corresponds to `Item` and edited column is your desired sheet (column `C` and sheet `Recipe Cards` in the spreadsheet you provided).
- If that's the case, check whether `Value` column (`D`) is equal to `Variable` and column `G` is equal to a certain string (called `Avoid future updates` in the sample below).
- If that's the case, set the value from `C` to `E` and write `Avoid future updates` to column `G`.

#### Code snippet:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const rowIndex = range.getRow();
  const colIndex = range.getColumn();
  const avoidUpdateColumn = 7;
  const itemColumn = 3;
  const valueColumn = 4;
  const fetchedItemColumn = 5;
  const copyValue = "Variable"; // Do not copy if column doesn't have this value
  const avoidUpdateValue = "Avoid future updates"; // Do not copy if column has this value
  const sheetName = "Recipe Cards";
  if (colIndex === itemColumn && sheet.getName() === sheetName) {
    const numCols = sheet.getLastColumn()-colIndex+1;
    const rowValues = sheet.getRange(rowIndex, colIndex, 1, numCols).getValues()[0];
    if (rowValues[valueColumn-itemColumn] === copyValue && rowValues[numCols-1] !== avoidUpdateValue) {
      sheet.getRange(rowIndex, fetchedItemColumn).setValue(rowValues[0]);
      sheet.getRange(rowIndex, avoidUpdateColumn).setValue(avoidUpdateValue);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)
- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: I'm having trouble getting Script Editor to even open. "Can't access the file" error. I'm sure your answer will work, so I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @Octotroph That's weird, have you checked whether this happens with other spreadsheets?